# Difference between using Laravel Cookie and plain php $_COOKIE?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I set a cookie with javascript and I'm trying to read on the backend with laravel PHP.. When I try running either of these, I get null:

```
Cookie::get('locale');
$locale = $request->cookie('locale');
```

Now when I run the plain old php version, I get the cookie normally.

```
$_COOKIE['locale'];
```

What's the difference? Why do I get null when using the laravel version?

Comment: how did you set your cookie is it via native php code ? if it is you must set it via laravel approach/code

Comment: I set it on frontend, with javascript

Comment: ah. I see that's why it returns null in laravel. maybe you set your cookie in laravel code via ajax. to be able to read it by laravel `Cookie` class since php framework(s) have their own array of session(s) and cookie(s)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel cookies are encrypted, so unless you do something like

```
return response('Hello World')->cookie(
    'locale', 'pt-BR'
);
```

You cant't read it using

```
Cookie::get('locale');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of laravel cookie encrypting. You can just not include `EncryptCookies` middleware to avoid this problem. Remove `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class` from `$middlewareGroups` in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

Comment: You can disable encryption for specific cookies instead of disabling it for everything (which would break secure sessions). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66859795/191890