# Laravel Request cookie doesn't show JS created Cookies

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using [JS-Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) for setting a Cookie via the front-end. 
Why can't I access it in my Laravel 5.8 application with:
`dd(request()->cookies)`? The Cookie is visible with the name, but the value is null. But when I do try to get the Value of the Cookie via the "normal" way, I do get the value: `dd($_COOKIE['the-cookie-value-i-want']);`.

How can I access the value of the Cookie via the "Laravel-way"? Which is more secure.

Comment: Might be that laravel cookies are encrypted. See this answer that showed up in related questions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42549165/3585500

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but you can disable encryption for specific cookies instead of disabling it for everything (which would break secure sessions).

Edit the `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies` class to include the following:

```
/**
 * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'my_frontend_cookie_name'
];
```

You can now access the cookie value via `request()->cookie()` or the `Cookie::get()` facade.

Answer (score 0):

**Only cookie created by laravel can handle by laravel.**

Now here is the way you can achieve this

Go to : **app > Http > Kernal.php** : under **$middlewareGroups** array comment this

```
 'web' => [
            //\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
```

And then try

Here is the demo

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{  Cookie::get('cookie1') }}
        {{  request()->cookie('cookie1') }}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.cookie = 'cookie1=test; path=/'
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```